# How to map collection attributes from Firestore to the cells of PlutoGrid?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to map the values from my query of Firestore to the right cells in the  right columns of the PlutoGrid structure. I think I'm almost there, but the last part is a little tricky.

This is part of my main code:

```
class RowInfinityScrollScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'feature/row-infinity-scroll';

  const RowInfinityScrollScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RowInfinityScrollScreenState createState() =>
      _RowInfinityScrollScreenState();
}

class _RowInfinityScrollScreenState extends State<RowInfinityScrollScreen> {
  late List<PlutoColumn> columns;
  late List<PlutoRow> rows;
  late PlutoGridStateManager stateManager;
  late List<PlutoRow> dBRows;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    columns = [
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Restaurants',
        field: 'name',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Stars',
        field: 'star',
        type: PlutoColumnType.number(),
      ),
    ];

    // Pass an empty row to the grid initially.
    rows = [];

    // fetch data from the server,
    dBRows = rowsByColumns(length: 100, columns: columns);    
  }

  static List<PlutoRow> rowsByColumns({
    required int length,
    required List<PlutoColumn> columns,
  }) {
    return List<int>.generate(length, (index) => index).map((_) {
      return rowByColumns(columns);
    }).toList();
  }

  static PlutoRow rowByColumns(List<PlutoColumn> columns) {
    return PlutoRow(cells: _cellsByColumn(columns));
  }

  static Map<String, PlutoCell> _cellsByColumn(List<PlutoColumn> columns) {
    final cells = <String, PlutoCell>{};
    for (var column in columns) {
      cells[column.field] = PlutoCell(
        value: DbService.withoutUID().getCollection(),
      );
    }
    return cells;
  }
```

and this is my getCollection method:

```
  Future<List> getCollection() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await bookiesCollection.get();
    List<dynamic> result = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    return result;
  }
```

Edit: The Data from QuerySnapshot looks like this:

```
{star: 4, name: Restaurant_0}
{star: 1, name: Restaurant_1}
{star: 5, name: Restaurant_2}
```

And I want the PlutoGrid to look like this:

```
Restaurant    |  Stars
--------------------
Restaurant_0  |  4
Restaurant_1  |  1
Restaurant_2  |  5
```

Comment: could you include the data you get from api?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I already have. It's at the end of the question. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Why you need to map? What do you get? What do you expect to get? You are getting errors, if yes post them in the question.

Comment: As you can see the PlutoColumnS are defined. At some point I have to map the data from firestore to the columns as rows. Atm I'm getting just the reference to the Future<List> in each and every row like 'Instance of '_Future<List<dynamic>>'

What I want I have edite in my question

Comment: Maybe edit the question and write what kind of data are you getting for `QuerySnapshot snapshot` and what kind of data you are getting for `List<dynamic> result`. And what kind of data are you writing here `value: DbService.withoutUID().getCollection()`, where from you are getting this data?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this:

```
  Future<PlutoInfinityScrollRowsResponse> fetch(
    PlutoInfinityScrollRowsRequest request,
  ) async {
    List<PlutoRow> tempList = rows;
    List<PlutoRow> currentRows = rows;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await bookiesCollection.get();
    for (var document in querySnapshot.docs) {
      PlutoRow row = PlutoRow(
        cells: {
          "name": PlutoCell(value: document['name']),
          "star": PlutoCell(value: document['star']),
        },
      );
      currentRows.add(row);
    }
    tempList = currentRows;
    ...
```